# Don't Safari support box-shadow?

Tags: safari, css

In my case, box-shadow in the Sarari of Win7 is fine.

But in Mac doesn't work. Should I use -webkit-box-shadow? But why box-shadow in the windows is OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari only supports the unprefixed version of `box-shadow` starting from version 5.1 on the desktop; older versions only support it via the vendor extension `-webkit-box-shadow`, as shown here: http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow

Your Mac's Safari may be 5.0 or older, while your Windows PC's Safari is at least version 5.1, which explains the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

`box-shadow` is the CSS3 property which is generic. But most of the browsers with `CSS3` support implement their own CSS3 attributes like `-webkit-box-shadow`, `-moz-box-shadow` etc. Recent versions of firefox, chrome, safari and opera support the generic `CSS3` properties. Check the version of safari you are using. But for cross browser compatibility, also include vendor specific CSS3 properties to maintain uniformity across all versions of browsers.